# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.loadCategories is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a React app.

This is my code. Why am I getting a error in the handleCategoryUpdated function?.

categoryManager.jsx:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.loadCategories is not a function.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { getCategories } from "../services/categoriesService";
import CategoryCard from "./categoryCard";
import CategoryEditor from "./categoryEditor";

class CategoryManager extends Component {
 state = {
  categories: [],
};

async componentDidMount() {
   await this.loadCategories();
}

 async loadCategories() {
    const categories = await getCategories();
    this.setState({ categories });
 }

async handleCategoryUpdated() {
    await this.loadCategories();
}

render() {
  const { categories } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Categories</h1>
      <CategoryEditor onCategoryUpdated={this.handleCategoryUpdated} />
      <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <CategoryCard category={category} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default CategoryManager;
```

Comment: Is this about binding to this?  https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html - you might need to bind loadCategories to `this` in the constructor or use the arrow syntax `loadCategories = () => { ... }`?

Comment: That was it. Answer the question and I will set it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as  mr rogers commented the issue is about `bind` of `this`.

If you are using a class component you can either use ES6 syntax for "autobind"

```js
async loadCategories() {
    const categories = await getCategories();
    this.setState({ categories });
}
```

Would be

```js
const loadCategories = async () => {
    const categories = await getCategories();
    this.setState({ categories });
}
```

Using arrow function and apply it to a constant on the class will make sure to bind the `this`.

Another way if you still want to use same syntax of functions inside the class you can use `bindAll` from `lodash` or manually bind the functions on the constructor.

```js
import _ form 'lodash';
class CategoryManager {
 constructor() {
   this.state = {
     categories: [],
   };

   // You can either use lodash here or manual bind
   _.bindAll(this, ['loadCategories']);

   // Or use manual bind
   this.loadCategories = this.loadCategories.bind(this);
 }

 async loadCategories() {
    const categories = await getCategories();
    this.setState({ categories });
 }
}
```